# Python 3 does not give a clean exit

Tags: python, user-interface, python-3.x, tkinter

This code does not give a clean exit when the Exit button is clicked. Instead, it hangs, leaaving the dead GUI.  Hw can we fix this?  A similar program in Python 2 behaves nicely.

```
from tkinter import *

import sys

root=Tk()
def quit():
    sys.exit("quitting")

frame=Frame()
frame.pack()

x=Label(root,text='Label')
x.pack()

y=Button(root,text='Button')
y.pack()

z=Button(root,text='Exit',command=quit)
z.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Just so you know, quit is a built-in. I'd choose a different name (e.g. quit_gui).

Comment: This was run on a student's windoze box.  it works proerly on my T60p running Ubuntu 10.10.  I shall pass along the suggestion below to him.

Comment: I also wouldn't `from tkinter import *`, since that just messes up Python's global namespace.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
def quit():
    root.destroy()
```

Should work...?